# What is the target when I use --native with Rust on a i7-1165G7 processor?

Tags: rust

When I compile the following function with the Rust 1.65 toolchain installed using Rustup, I get assembly that doesn't use the `popcnt` instruction:

```rust
pub fn f(x:u64) -> u32 {
    x.count_ones()
}
```

To make it generate `popcnt`, I need to pass `--native`.

`rustup show` says:

```
$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

and `lscpu` says:

```
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  8
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
```

So, in this case what is the actual target used when I pass `--native` if it's not `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`?

Comment: Target triples are "lowest common denominator" meant to produce portable binaries compatible with any CPU of that architecture. When you pass `-C target-cpu=native` to rustc, it doesn't change the target, it just tells the codegen to produce code specialized for the CPU on the current machine.

Comment: @PitaJ Does that mean there is no identifiable target? Just "native"? Wondering if I can reference this specific "native" by name.

Comment: Again, it's not a target, it's a codegen option. Try `rustc --print target-cpus`. It should start with something like `native       - Select the CPU of the current host (currently <yours>)`

Comment: I believe the default is `generic`. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#target-cpu

Comment: Very likely, "native" for your CPU means ["tigerlake"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_Lake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target defined for your architecture is still `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.  That triple basically means that your CPU is `x86_64` (that is, an x86-64), the vendor is `unknown` (which is typically the case unless there's a relevant set of vendors with functional differences), and the OS is `linux-gnu` (that is, a Linux kernel with the GNU toolchain and userland, including glibc).

Now, there are a wide variety of x86-64 processors with varying capabilities.  In fact, I dare say that x86-64 provides the largest possible set of instruction capabilities.  All of those machines running Linux with the GNU userland will be `x86-64-unknown-linux-gnu`.  By default, Rust targets a generic CPU; that is, it writes code that will work on all processors that meet the x86-64 architectural definition.  That means that it will use SSE2, which is part of the architectural definition, but not POPCNT, which came along later and is not.

In most cases, that's exactly what you want.  It is almost always far more important to have a binary that just works than one tuned to the local system, and that's usually what distro maintainers and packagers want as well.

However, if you need the POPCNT instruction, then `--native` can work.  If you do `rustc --print target-cpus | head -n2`, then you'll see something like this:

```
Available CPUs for this target:
    native         - Select the CPU of the current host (currently alderlake).
```

In my case, this is `alderlake`.  You will *probably* see `tigerlake` there, but I don't have such a system, so you'll have to look for yourself.